# Custom response headers not sent by server (Rails Devise)

Tags: http, tcp, okhttp

I'm trying to retrieve 3 response headers (Rails Devise Auth Headers: uid, client, access-token) in every request to a Rails Server.

Using Postman (http client) it's working.
With OkHttp (java http client) the headers just don't show up in the client (i've checked using Wireshark).
When i'm in debug mode it just work...

Comment: Headers sent after the body sound like chunked encoding with headers in the chunked trailer. This is a very rarely used and supported feature so I doubt it is done that way. Please provide more details about the data actually send, i.e. post packet captures for both postman and OkHttp to cloudshark.org.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i'll prepare more information.

Comment: Postman packets: https://www.cloudshark.org/captures/325740cea0ab

Comment: OkHttp packets: https://www.cloudshark.org/captures/9e69f16fb85f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The additional headers with postman are due to postman sending  an Origin header and the server is replying with [CORS](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) headers, i.e. `Access-Control-...`. These headers are send within the normal HTTP header, i.e. not after the response.

But these access control headers are only relevant when the access is done from a browser because they control the cross origin behavior of [XHR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest). Since you are not inside a browser they should be irrelevant for what you are doing. What is relevant are the body of the response and some of the other headers and here you'll find no differences. Also irrelevant should be if multiple requests are send within the same TCP connection (HTTP keep-alive done by postman) or with multiple connections (OkHttp) because each request is independent from the other and using the same TCP connection is only a performance optimization.

If you really want to get these special headers you should add an Origin header within you OkHttp request. See [the OkHttp examples](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/AccessHeaders.java) on how to add your own headers. But like I said: these access control headers should be irrelevant for the real task and there should be no need to get to these headers.

Comment: Sorry, I realize that I didn't explained the intent on this. I'm trying to retrieve those uid, client and access-token headers cause server will always update client and access-token values and send me back on every response. Then I want to retrieve the headers on the "/api/v1/patients/:id:timelines" response to authenticate on every folling request i.e. sign_in > timeline page 1 > timeline page 2 (3 distinct requests).

Comment: @PatrickMachado: according to the packet capture the headers you want to retrieve are in the response you got for your OkHttp request. So where exactly is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that they are only in the sign_in request, i need them in the timeline request too.

Comment: @PatrickMachado: they are in the sign_in *response*. You need to extract these headers from there and put them into the following timeline *request* yourself. How should OkHttp know by itself that these headers are important and need to be transferred into the following request?

Comment: Sorry, I mean that i need them into timeline response. Let me try to be more specific. First i request a sign in, the response will give me the auth headers (uid, client and access token), then add those auth headers into timeline request (to authenticate), once i got timeline response i need the auth headers updated in this response to send them in future requests i.e. timeline page 2. Every response will update the values of the auth headers.

Comment: @PatrickMachado: since the capture for OkHttp currently does not contain the timeline request I have no idea what you are actually sending and what you get back. Please add another capture which shows the problem you have and not only what happened before the problem.

Comment: The OkHttp capture contain the timeline request... It's GET /api/v1/patients/7/timelines?page=1&per_page=5
https://www.cloudshark.org/captures/9e69f16fb85f

Comment: @PatrickMachado: I see and this is very strange. I think you are dealing with a server here which has some unusual requirements on the client. You might try to add an `Accept: */*` header to the request like Postman does to see if this help. And you might look at errors or debugging info at the server side which indicate that the server is missing something specific from the client. It's really hard to speculate without having access to the server and playing with different requests. But it is definitely not that OkHttp is ignoring the headers - the server is not sending these.

Comment: I tried to use Accept: */* and it didn't work. I will ask for the guys in the server to debug this. Once we found something i let you know. Really thank for your help.

Comment: We found the problem! It was a configuration on Rails Devise (Server).

Answer (score 0):

There is a property "config.batch_request_buffer_throttle" in the file "config/initializers/devise_token_auth.rb" of the Rails Project. We changed it from 5 seconds to 0 seconds.
It is a property to keep the current token available for that amount of time to the following requests.
As the original documentation: "Sometimes it's necessary to make several requests to the API at the same time. In this case, each request in the batch will need to share the same auth token. This setting determines how far apart the requests can be while still using the same auth token."

So when we did the request using Postman or in Java Debug the 5 seconds was running allowing Devise to generate new tokens then retrieve them to the client.